# Ubuntu not detecting wired headset

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio

Do forgive me as I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. I was given a computer to use for work but it requires a headset. I have one but the computer is not detecting it at all. It does not show up in pulse or in lsusb whatsoever. Is there any way to fix this? Any help would be so appreciated as I need this to work for my job. I have done searches for this issue but nobody else seems to be having this exact problem. It's a Logitech G432 headset for reference.

Comment: If you aren't connecting it via USB it won't show up anywhere. Ubuntu release/version?

Comment: On their website (https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/products/gaming-audio/g432-7-1-surround-sound-gaming-headset.981-000769.html#product-tech-specs) it says ```USB 2.0 port or higher for PCs, Mac, Nintendo Switch, PlayStation 4; 3.5 mm audio port for console or mobile devices ```. Do you get any sound from the 3,5 mm jack? Or are you only using the USB?